# Can output range of algorithms in <numeric> in C++ overlap with the input range?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, stl-algorithm

There are six algorithms that will output a range(which is denoted by an output iterator) in `<numeric>`: `adjacent_difference`, `partial_sum`, `inclusive_scan`, `exclusive_scan`, `transform_inclusive_scan` and `transform_exclusive_scan`. Can their input ranges overlap with output ranges? What about their parallel version?

I've tried to find some hints in the C++ standard with no luck.

Comment: In cppreference, for [`inclusive_scan`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inclusive_scan) *"d_first - the beginning of the destination range; may be equal to first"*.

Comment: I would expect that the parallel versions would not be able to share an input and output range, but I haven't checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the remarks at https://eel.is/c++draft/numeric.ops.

Search for 'Remarks: result may be equal to first'

All of the algorithms that you asked about *except* `adjacent_difference` have that remark.

So the output range can be the same as the input range.  That's more restrictive than what you asked about (can they overlap).